# Cropping face using dlib facial landmarks

Tags: python, opencv, dlib

I am trying to crop a face using the facial landmarks identified by dlib. The right eyebrow is causing problems - the crop goes flat across rather than follow the eyebrow arc.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
from imutils import face_utils
import imutils
import numpy as np
import collections
import dlib
import cv2

def face_remap(shape):
   remapped_image = shape.copy()
   # left eye brow
   remapped_image[17] = shape[26]
   remapped_image[18] = shape[25]
   remapped_image[19] = shape[24]
   remapped_image[20] = shape[23]
   remapped_image[21] = shape[22]
   # right eye brow
   remapped_image[22] = shape[21]
   remapped_image[23] = shape[20]
   remapped_image[24] = shape[19]
   remapped_image[25] = shape[18]
   remapped_image[26] = shape[17]
   # neatening 
   remapped_image[27] = shape[0]

   return remapped_image

"""
MAIN CODE STARTS HERE
"""
# load the input image, resize it, and convert it to grayscale
image = cv2.imread("images/faceCM1.jpg")
image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

out_face = np.zeros_like(image)

# initialize dlib's face detector (HOG-based) and then create the facial landmark predictor
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(SHAPE_PREDICTOR)

# detect faces in the grayscale image
rects = detector(gray, 1)

# loop over the face detections
for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
   """
   Determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy array
   """
   shape = predictor(gray, rect)
   shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

   #initialize mask array
   remapped_shape = np.zeros_like(shape) 
   feature_mask = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))   

   # we extract the face
   remapped_shape = face_remap(shape)
   cv2.fillConvexPoly(feature_mask, remapped_shape[0:27], 1)
   feature_mask = feature_mask.astype(np.bool)
   out_face[feature_mask] = image[feature_mask]
   cv2.imshow("mask_inv", out_face)
   cv2.imwrite("out_face.png", out_face)
```

[sample image of cropped face showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ1xF.png)

Comment: Im not entirely sure you are doing anything wrong, isn't it only supposed to detect those points? [source](http://www.codesofinterest.com/2017/04/extracting-individual-facial-features-dlib.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because the face shape you are providing is not convex. 
fillConvexPoly works perfectly on convex shapes only, In this case there is a concave corner (at point #27) and hence the results are messed up.

To fix this, modify the function as

```
def face_remap(shape):
    remapped_image = cv2.convexHull(shape)
    return remapped_image
```

This would give you a result which looks like. 
[image]

Now you may write some more code to remove the triangular section on forehead (if you want it that way)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, that solved the problem perfectly! Now that you mention it, pt #16 - pt #17 looks like a concave corner as well and was well tolerated by fillConvexPoly(). Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: There would always be some errors while fitting the points using dlib. In case of point #15-16-17, they are mostly in a straight line. Even a slightest error might push point #16 on the left making it a concave corner.

Fixing this would require you to find a subset of points in shape but not in cv2.convexHull(shape). And they loop over those points to cover the rest of the area.

Answer (score 5):

Using the convex hull formed by the 68 landmarks didn't exactly achieve the desired output, so I had the following approach to this problem using [`scikit-image`](https://scikit-image.org/) instead of OpenCV

**1. Load image and predict 68 landmarks**

```
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')

img = dlib.load_rgb_image('mean.jpg')

rect = detector(img)[0]
sp = predictor(img, rect)
landmarks = np.array([[p.x, p.y] for p in sp.parts()])
```

[image]

**2. Select the landmarks that represents the shape of the face**

(I had to reverse the order of the eyebrows landmarks because the [68 landmarks](https://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/resources/facial-point-annotations/) aren't ordered to describe the face outline)

```
outline = landmarks[[*range(17), *range(26,16,-1)]]
```

[image]

**3. Draw a polygon using these landmarks using `scikit-image`**

```
Y, X = skimage.draw.polygon(outline[:,1], outline[:,0])
```

[image]

**4. Create a canvas with zeros and use the polygon as mask to original image**

```
cropped_img = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
cropped_img[Y, X] = img[Y, X]
```

[image]

---

For the sake of completeness, I provide below a solution using [scipy.spatial.ConvexHull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html), if this option is still preferred

```
vertices = ConvexHull(landmarks).vertices
Y, X = skimage.draw.polygon(landmarks[vertices, 1], landmarks[vertices, 0])
cropped_img = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
cropped_img[Y, X] = img[Y, X]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Great answer! By the way, on the landmarks selection, `outline = landmarks[[*range(17), *range(26,16,-1)]]` , that sounds like it would get the result as `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17]` . Shouldn't `[*range(1,18), *range(27,17,-1)]` be better? Because it will get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18]` .

Comment: @tli2020 The [68 landmarks](https://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/media/uploads/images/annotpics/figure_68_markup.jpg) seen in the picture starts at `1`, whereas the `dlib` implementation starts at `0`, so the indexes we want for the face shape are `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17]`