# Dlib - Segmenting (cropping) Face with Forehead

Tags: python-3.x, dlib

I recently followed the walkthrough described in this link:
[Cropping face using dlib facial landmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712766/cropping-face-using-dlib-facial-landmarks)

The goal was to remove the background from a sequence of images and rebuild a face by photogrammetry with the output files.

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCwI7.png)

It worked, but as I intend to use the result for research in the area of human health, it is essential that the person's forehead appears and in this case the segmentation is done just above the eyebrow.

[Intended Result at right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8PmG.jpg)

I would like to know if there would be a way to segment encompassing the forehead as well.

I tried using the shape with 81 markers, but it didn't work out. Would it be possible to scale only in Y or even duplicate the mask to move the second mask up a little (+Y), join them with a bool (union) and create an output image with the forehead?

Thank you so much for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED!] I found a .dat with forehead:

https://github.com/codeniko/shape_predictor_81_face_landmarks/blob/master/shape_predictor_81_face_landmarks.dat